# Advanced Custom Fields functionality without plugin

Tags: custom-field, wysiwyg

I am always looking to minimise my reliance on plugins. I currently use Advanced Custom Fields plugin for pretty much every site I build.

I can't help but feel that the functionality this plugin brings should be (and probably is) something the WP supports, i.e. multiple WYSIWYG blocks per template/specific pages.

Could anyone suggest a way of having multiple editable content sections (specifically WYSIWYG) on a page without using plugins?

I am aware of the capability of adding meta boxes for single text fields, etc, but that's not what I am actually after.

Comment: Look at the plugin source and see how it does things.

Comment: What are you after? If you don't want a plugin to add custom fields, you have to do it on your own. You need a couple of functions - one to create the meta box, one to save it's input and I think that's pretty much it. In your meta box you can have whatever you want, including a WYSIWYG field.

Comment: Elliot (the ACF dev) is actually releasing a "lite" version of the plugin next week so theme/plugin devs can include it without depending on the ACF plugin. All the goodness, none of the unneeded fluff

Comment: What is inherently wrong with using Plugins? If the Plugin is coded properly, it will be as - if not *more* - efficient than incorporating the same code directly into your Theme (where custom post meta data generally *doesn't* belong, anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys - very helpful. There is nothing inherently wrong with plugins apart from that as a developer I want to be able to make my own plugins customised to each job I take on. This is a fundamental of that objective. Now it has been made clear that using custom fields and meta boxes I can achieve this makes my life a whole lot easier. From the codex I presumed it was just for check boxes or single line text fields. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

> I am aware of the capability of adding meta boxes for single text fields, etc, but that's not what I am actually after.

Meta fields aren't just for "single text fields", the database type is `longtext`:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE wp_postmeta;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| meta_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| meta_key   | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meta_value | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

This is intentional so you can store just about anything you want in a meta field. When you create your meta box you can use any form input you like as long as you handle it correctly when saving the post.